# Timed on/off switch problem

Tags: current, ac, delay

I'm doing a small project for my school and the main point of my problem is that I need a simple circuit, that could activate for a fixed time when the mains power goes on.

For example:
I have a TV, and when it is plugged in an on/off switch should be pressed and held down for 5 seconds to turn it on. What I want to do, is to automate the process of creating contact of that on/off switch with some basic electronics and/or maybe with an IC.

Basically:

1)AC power comes to TV and small circuit that converts it to DC.

2)Another circuit simulates the push of power button for 3-5s and after that stays off till AC current appears again.

Maybe anyone knows some schematics or other material, I could read, to solve this problem?

Comment: It would be simpler to have always on like NC contact of relay, that after a AC mains comes on, it switches on a relay trough RC delay circuit and stays on until AC power is on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some commercial solution that seems to do what you want:

- [intermatic.com/.../ei400_series](http://www.intermatic.com/en/products/timers/inwalltimers/electronic_timers/ei400_series)
- [quasarelectronics.co.uk/.../Velleman K8075](https://www.quasarelectronics.co.uk/index.php?app=ecom&ns=catshow&ref=1m800p090c20s&sid=448w85hj47666s4131b96pjup6n2zl9k)

To build it yourself the most popular solution is a 555 timer, may circuit schematics are available online. Add an appropriate bridge rectifier to replace the VCC/Battery input and a relay at the output for AC operation. This link is the opposite of your application, but the "edits" illustrate how to add the rectifier and relay:

- electrolund.com/2007/10/ac-outlet-timer-circuit/

This link uses a 7555 with a range of resistance values for adjustable timing:

- www.zen22142.zen.co.uk/Circuits/Timing/5_30timer.htm

Have Fun!